# Avoid EditText TextWatcher firing events on every character change

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

I use an EditText textField with TextWatcher attached. All of the callback methods fire events on every character I enter. In my case I call an api on text changed, to put the response into a label on the same fragment. I can not check the EditText for a certain format as it will be freetext.

Example:
Whats your name?

```
E -> api call 
R -> api call
I _> api call
K -> api call
```

How to avoid that? Can I use a timer (eg 2 seconds no text changed -> api call)? Maybe there is an elegant way of doing that.

Comment: What are you using Java or kotlin?

Comment: You will want to look at using "debounce" techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Kotlin, you can do this with a coroutine. For example, if you want to run the API call 2 seconds after the text has stopped changing it would look like this:

**In the Activity or Fragment with a ViewModel**

```kotlin
val model: MainViewModel by viewModels()

binding.textInput.doAfterTextChanged { e ->
    e?.let { model.registerChange( it.toString() ) }
}
```

**In the ViewModel**

```kotlin
private var job: Job? = null

fun registerChange(s: String) {
    job?.cancel() // cancel prior job on a new change in text
    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(2_000)
        println("Do API call with $s")
    }
}
```

**Or without using a ViewModel**

```kotlin
private var job: Job? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.textInput.doAfterTextChanged { e ->
        e?.let { 
            job?.cancel()
            job = lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(1_000)
                println("Do API call with ${it}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Using Jetpack Compose**

The solution using Jetpack Compose is the same, just added to the `onValueChange` lambda instead of `doAfterTextChanged` (either in place, or the same ViewModel call as before).

```kotlin
private var job: Job? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val textState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        TextField(
            value = textState.value,
            onValueChange = {
                textState.value = it
                job?.cancel()
                job = lifecycleScope.launch {
                    delay(2_000)
                    println("TEST: Do API call with $it")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Java Solution**

If you are using Java, you could use a handler and a postDelayed runnable instead but the flow would be the same (on a text change, cancel the prior task and start a new one with a delay).

```java
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText textInput = findViewById(R.id.text_input);
    textInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if( s != null ) {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Call API with " + s.toString());
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler! The solution is technically what I was searching for and the delay in potential error messages is appealing.

Comment: This works perfectly for a debounce, thank you!