# How to detect if the user stops writing to a TextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen with Jetpack Compose in which I have a TextField for the user to write a text.

With this text I will make a query to obtain data. I want this query to be made when the user finishes typing.

Is there a way to know if the user takes 2 seconds without writing (for example) to launch this query?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632237/avoid-edittext-textwatcher-firing-events-on-every-character-change/70633680#70633680) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose and Room DB: Performance overhead of auto-saving user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689839/jetpack-compose-and-room-db-performance-overhead-of-auto-saving-user-input)

Comment: Kotlin supports onblurchangelisteners that fire if a user disables focus on the TextField. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 20):

Another way is to avoid the viewmodel completely. Utilise the [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) that will cancel/restart itself on every key (text) change. I find this to be way cleaner than to couple your debounce code to your viewmodel.

```
@Composable
private fun TextInput(
    dispatch: (ViewModelEvent) : Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    var someInputText by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

    TextField(
        value = someInputText,
        onValueChange = {
            someInputText = it
        },
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = someInputText) {
        // this check is optional if you want the value to emit from the start
        if (someInputText.text.isBlank()) return@LaunchedEffect

        delay(2000)
        // print or emit to your viewmodel
        dispatch(SomeViewModelEvent(someInputText.text))
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not help, you are calling the function upon every event, just with a delay. Its not the same as debounce.

Comment: From the documentation:

*"If LaunchedEffect is recomposed with different keys (see the Restarting Effects section below), the existing coroutine will be cancelled and the new suspend function will be launched in a new coroutine."*

Meaning the actual dispatch will be called ONLY when 2 seconds elapse and no further changes to the input were made

Answer (score 8):

To query after 2 seconds after user stop typing, I think you can use debounce operator (similar idea to the answer here [Jetpack Compose and Room DB: Performance overhead of auto-saving user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689839/jetpack-compose-and-room-db-performance-overhead-of-auto-saving-user-input))

Here is an example to handle text change on `TextField`, then query to database and return the result to `dbText`

```
class VM : ViewModel() {
    val text = MutableStateFlow("")
    val dbText = text.debounce(2000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest {
            queryFromDb(it)
        }

    private fun queryFromDb(query: String): Flow<String> {
        Log.i("TAG", "query from db: " + query)
        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            return flowOf("Empty Result")
        }
        // TODO, do query from DB and return result
    }
}
```

In `Composable`

```
Column {
    val text by viewModel.text.collectAsState()
    val dbText by viewModel.dbText.collectAsState("Empty Result")

    TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { viewModel.text.value = it })
    Text(text = dbText)
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. Just don't forget to launch it in viewmodel scope with `launchIn(viewModelScope)` or  `viewModelScope.launch { }`. Otherwise `.flatMapLatest { queryFromDb(it) }` doesn't trigger like in my case :)

Comment: Two years later and it's still experimental :-\